# Problem with installing dropbox

Tags: installation, proxy, dropbox

I am trying to install "Dropbox" on my laptop and it keeps throwing the following error at me all the time.

```
laptop@laptop:~$ dropbox start -i

Starting Dropbox...
Dropbox is the easiest way to share and store your files online. Want to learn more? 

Error: Trouble connecting to Dropbox servers. Maybe your internet connection is down, or you need to set your http_proxy environment variable
The installation of Dropbox failed.
```

I have tried

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
```

which results in

```
--2013-01-17 17:53:28--  Resolving proxy.hs-karlsruhe.de (proxy.hs-karlsruhe.de)... 193.196.64.2
Connecting to proxy.hs-karlsruhe.de (proxy.hs-karlsruhe.de)|193.196.64.2|:8888... connected.
Proxy tunneling failed: Proxy Authentication RequiredUnable to establish SSL connection.

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Then I've tried

```
https_proxy=http://proxy.hs-karlsruhe.de:8888 dropbox start -i
```

and that gives an error message too. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

> Proxy tunneling failed: Proxy Authentication Required

You have to provide username and password to authenticate with the proxy. Try the following:

```
export http_proxy="http://<username>:<password>@proxy.hs-karlsruhe.de:8888"
export https_proxy="http://<username>:<password>@proxy.hs-karlsruhe.de:8888"
```

then run `dropbox start -i`.

Comment: We don't have a username and password system. The system admin of the university approves network access through a MAC ID of the laptop based system. I am not really sure how it works. We submit out MAC ID to the sys admin and we get access to the college wi-fi.

Comment: @VarunKShetty Well, the fact is that the proxy is requesting authentication. You should talk to your sys admin and show him this error message.